# Open a GUI Application on remote desktop using SSH session

Tags: ssh, remote-desktop

**Note** I am not asking for opening remote desktop's GUI on my local system via SSH Session. (x11)

Here is my problem,
I have a script, say `script.exe` that launches calc.exe, performs addition of 2 numbers by automating click events (via the help of Winium), reads results and output it to console.

Now I wish to launch this script on the remote desktop which I am connected to from my local system via an SSH Session.

```
ssh Admin@abc
Admin@abc C:\Users\Admin\Desktop>script.exe
```

This certainly doesn't seem to work as there is no active desktop on the remote machine. I would like to know how can we achieve this. Also, I am open to solutions that do not include SSH but gets the job done.

Hope anyone helps 
Regards

Comment: So did you have any success with that?